# Characterising when a power of a convex sum is a convex sum with the same weights

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, convex-analysis

Let $I$ be a finite set. For each $i \in I$ let $(x^{(i)}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be monotonically increasing sequence of strictly positive integers. Under what conditions on the sequences $(x^{(i)}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  do there exist weights $p_i\ge 0$ (that is $\sum_{i \in I}p_i = 1$) so that we have the equality

$$
\Big(\sum_{i \in I} p_i x^{(i)}_1 \Big)^n = \sum_{i \in I} p_ix_n^{(i)}
$$
 for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I know, for example, that we get equality if $p_i = 1/|I|$ and for each $i$ and $n$ we have $x_n^{(i)} = a^n$ for some positive integer $a$.

In general, is there a characterisation of the allowable sequences?